# Android string resource variable not appearing if between characters

Tags: android, xml, string, android-resources

This shows the integer fine `<string name="count"> Count %d </string>`

Example output: `Count 3`

however this does not, `<string name="count"> Count ( %d )</string>`

Example output: `Count`

I need to integer to be displayed between the parentheses, is this not achievable via the strings.xml file? I would rather not use a `SpannableString` and keep it simple with the string variable.

I'm using android Context class to get the string

```
@NonNull
public final String getString(@StringRes int resId, Object... formatArgs) {
    return getResources().getString(resId, formatArgs);
}
```

so... `viewObject.text = context.getString(R.string.filter, integerCount)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some characters in xml need to be escaped. You can use in your case :

```
"&#40;" for ( 
and 
"&#41;" for )
```